# Tracking Share-drive Users name and opening time in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have found a similar article about my question, as stated below;

[How do I track who uses my Excel spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319162/how-do-i-track-who-uses-my-excel-spreadsheet/18320244#18320244?newreg=2315406bbb484d41b95ace77f114e199)

However, I do like the last coloumn of comment >>
"You could also put a time stamp in the next column to show when the spreadsheet was used"

My question is>  can anyone guide me the possible step or let me copy the code for doing this please? and how to hide the worksheet without anyone noticing?
My key is, very importantly, everything must done silently which no one else (other users in sharedrive) could find out i m tracking it. The reason is , i have done lot of research worksheets, and i don't have time/impossible to make every single excel worksheet perfect, i need to prioritize them inorder to be efficient with my time by knowing which one is more important to people.

many thanks~!!

Comment: Also, to follow the excel coding marcos stated in the article "How do I track who uses my Excel spreadsheet?' the automatically send email function when excel file is open > can i set something in the coding, that making it stop sending email WHEN I am the one opening it? thanksssss

Comment: First I would like to note that there is no need to comment on your own post. You can `edit` your post and change it to amend the above comment. Afterwards, you can delete the above comment using the small `x` next to it. In respect to your above post I'd like to advise you not to attempt that in Excel. There is no (limited and can be easily overcome) security in Excel. If you want / have to track their doings then I'd recommend connecting the Excel file(s) to an SQL Server and do the tracking there. Whatever you are doing in Excel cannot be hidden effectively.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, under the Review tab, you have 'Track Changes'.  This should do everything you want.

If you want a VBA script to do this, try one of the following code samples.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Set t = Target
Set a = Range("A:A")
If Intersect(t, a) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
t.Offset(0, 7).Value = Environ("username")
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim V As Long
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set rng1 = Application.Union(Range("a1:g1"), Range("H:iv"))
Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, rng1)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

V = Target.Offset(0, 12).Value
If Target.Offset(0, 12) = "" Then
    With Range("H" & Target.Row)
       .Value = Target.Address & ": first entry by " & Application.UserName & " at " & Now()
       .ColumnWidth = 60
       .Interior.ColorIndex = 33
    End With
    Target.Offset(0, 12).Value = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
End If
Target.Offset(0, 12).Value = Target.Value
With Range("H" & Target.Row)
  .Value = Target.Address & " changed from " & V & " to " & Target.Value & " by " & Application.UserName & " at " & Now()
   .ColumnWidth = 60
  .Interior.Color = vbYellow
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
        With Target
            If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            If Not Intersect(Range("A2:A10"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                    .Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
                Else
                    With .Offset(0, 1)
                        .NumberFormat = "dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                        .Value = Now
                    End With
                End If
                Sheets("Sheet1").Select
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
End Sub
```

All of these 'Worksheet_Change' scripts are worksheet events.  You need to right-click your sheet and click 'View Code' then paste the script into the window that opens.  Try one at a time, not all three together.